# How do I test a LCD monitor's performance & quality?

Tags: display, performance, lcd

How do I test a LCD monitor's quality and performance? It would be great if I can estimate the remaining lifespan of the monitor.

Answer (score 3):

The "test cards" found at http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/ are useful for checking your monitors colour balance and other properties, to see if your monitor is good, bad or simple not setup properly for your environment. The sync test cards are useful for ensuring you have good adjustment of analog settings if you are not using a DVI or other digital connection to control the screen. There is also an amount of useful background information about each test and the properties it concerns.